# Microsoft Edge - Show all tabs in task bar

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-edge

One of the things that I liked about Internet Explorer was that it showed all of the tabs that you had opened in the task bar. Microsoft Edge has gone down the same path as Chrome, showing each window in the task bar and not each tab. Is there a way to change this back to the IE behaviour?

Answer (score 1):

This is not currently an option with Microsoft Edge. To submit feedback, run the Windows Feedback tool and vote on an existing suggestion in the Microsoft Edge category.